# Fixed React Navbar

Tags: reactjs, navbar, materialize, fixed

I am using Materialize UI with React and I am trying to make the navbar on top fixed, however, I am getting a big gap on the left-hand side of the navbar that pushes the entire navbar itself to the right (see photo).

[image]

How can I make that gap in front disappear? Sorry, if this is a silly question but it's my first time trying to build an actual web app with React.

Thanks.

```
// App.js

import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './Header';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/"/>
        <Header />
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
};

export default App;
```

```
// Header.js

import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => {
    return (
     <div className='container'>
         <div className="navbar-fixed">
          <nav className="teal">
           <div className="nav-wrapper">
            <Link to="#home" className="brand-logo">Travelville</Link>
            <Link to="#" data-activates="mobile-nav" className="button-collapse">
              <i className="material-icons">menu</i>
            </Link>
            <ul className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
              <li>
                <Link to="#home">Home</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="#search">Search</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="#popular">Popular Places</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="#gallery">Gallery</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="#contact">Contact</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
         </nav>
      </div>
      <ul className="side-nav" id="mobile-nav">
      <li>
        <Link to="#home">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="#search">Search</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="#popular">Popular Places</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="#gallery">Gallery</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="#contact">Contact</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: Can you please also show your css/scss files?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I don't actually have a css for this project as I am using Materialize UI. According to their documentation <div className='navbar-fixed'> should fix the navbar on top. It does just that when I create a static html page but as soon as I start using React and use it in JSX it seems to put a gap in front of the navbar. When I use Chrome dev tools, the space seems to be created by <div id='root'> in the index html where App renders to. Just putting the html here in case:

Comment: That is the html part
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: Not to worry, I got it fixed now by making a css for the root element position absolute, thanks.